# Gather specific elements from multiple registers and store to one register

Tags: c, x86, sse, intrinsics, avx

Let's assume I have 8 SSE registers, enumerated as r0,r1,r2,...,r7, and each contains, let's say, 8 16-bit integers. I would like to create a new register which contains the i-th element of each of the  8 registers, starting from r0, going to r7. In other words, I would like to obtain a register with the following contents:

`r0[i],r1[i],r2[i],r3[i],r4[i],r5[i],r6[i],r7[i]`

How would that be done using SSE (or AVX)?

Thanks!

Note that the index i is not a constant number and is computed at run-time.

Comment: What you're trying to do what you have described will be amazingly slow. Are you trying to do a transpose or something?

Comment: You can do this with 7 PSHUFB instructions, but it might be better if you added some explanation of what you're trying to achieve by doing this, as there may be a better overall solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hard to explain, but in principle I'm computing a matrix column by column using SSE. The result is the last column and last row of the matrix. I have vectorized the method by using vectors of 8 16-bit values for computing the matrix, column by column. I have padded the column length (clen) of the matrix to be a multiple of 8, such that I do clen/8 vector computation per column. I'm always overwriting the computation, i.e. in memory I always have the result of only the previous column. In the end of the computation, the result is the last column (which I Want).

Comment: (continued) Now I also want the last row. I  unrolled the loop of column traversal such that I compute 8 columns in one iteration of the loop, and keep the last vector of each column in a register. After 8 columns are processed, I have 8 SSE registers that contain the last vector of 8 columns and I end up with the described problem. Remember that I padded clen, and so the i index I describe is (clen-1)%8. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want people to take your question seriously you're going to have to show some code not just say what you're doing in multiple paragraphs.

Comment: Depending on what else you're doing at the same time it might be more efficient to do a single 8x8 transpose (@ 24 instructions) rather than extracting individual columns (@ 7 instructions), i.e. if you're extracting more than 3 columns from the same matrix then a transpose wins.

Comment: @PaulR: this old unanswered question got me curious: how can you do this with 7 insns?  `PSHUFB` can't move data between registers, so 7x `PSHUFB` can get you `r_n[n] = old_r_n[i]`, but then you need to `OR` them together.  Maybe with 7 `SHUFPS` instructions for 32b elements?  AMD XOP `VPPERM` selects each element from any element of two source regs, so a chain / tree of `VPPERM`s would work.

Comment: @PeterCordes: sorry, I can't remember exactly what I had in mind when I wrote that - it may just have been a combination of hubris and not thinking through all the details. I certainly wasn't thinking of AMD instructions though. I'll give it some more thought and come back to this if I get any inspiration.

Comment: @PaulR: don't worry about it, I don't have any desire to write code that does this.  It just seemed like an interesting challenge.  I'm thinking maybe the shuffle mask to use for `xmmN` can be `table[ (i-N) & 7]` or something?  To avoid doing an 8th shuffle with a mask that just zeroes all but the desired element, without moving it, I think you'd need a `switch(i)`.  So I think Mysticial wasn't exaggerating by saying: amazingly slow.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed like an interesting challenge.  If you ever need to do this in your algorithm, it's time to think about how else to organize things so you *don't* have to do *just* this, instead of something like a whole 8x8 transpose as Paul R suggested in comments.

I'm thinking of something like a `pshufb` for every register, to set

```
xmmN[N] = old_xmmN[i]; // with other elements zeroed.
```

You'd have a table of shuffle masks, and use `table[ (i-N) & 7]` for shufflign `xmmN`.  Or, with duplication of shuffle masks before/after zero, you could just use 8 consecutive masks starting at `table[i]`.  (So you compute the address into a register once, and use increasing displacements.

Then `POR` the registers together in a tree.  (Actually, choose operands for the first `POR` and schedule it right after the first two `PSHUFB`s, so the combining can overlap with the shuffling.)

You might get better throughput by storing to memory, then reloading.   (but maybe worse latency, because of the store-forwarding delay this will cause.)

```
rdi = tmp buffer
switch(i) {
    case 0:
        movd   [rdi],   xmm0
        movd   [rdi+2], xmm1
        ...
        movd   [rdi+14], xmm8  // note: writes all the way to [rdi+17].  use pextrw to avoid that.
        break;
    case 1:
        pextrw [rdi],   xmm0, 1;  // SSE4.1 for memory dest pextrw
        pextrw [rdi+2], xmm1, 1
        ...
        break;
    case 2:
        same, but with imm8 = 2;
        break;
    ...
}
movdqa xmm0, [rdi]   ;// ~10 cycle store-forwarding stall
```